# package.json scripts on windows literal * character

Tags: node.js, package.json, npm-scripts

I need to pass in a literal not-to-be-expanded argument `zzz/*.js`  to a nodejs script `yyy` called from a package.json "scripts" script.  This works fine on Linux

```
  "scripts":{
    "xxx": "yyy 'zzz/*.js'"
  },
```

where the single quotes suppress expansion and the literal string `zzz/*.js` is passed to `yyy`.

However on windows, at least in a traditional command shell, the single quotes are included so the argument passed is `'zzz/*.js'`.

Is there a succinct way to pass the argument that is guaranteed to work on Linux and *any* Windows shell used to execute `package.json` scripts? (Same command for both systems.)  Preferably not escaping every possible glob character because that is very cluttered.

Answer (score 2):

Double quotes work for both Linux and Windows:

```
  "scripts":{
    "xxx": "yyy \"zzz/*.js\""
  }
```